# python module not found error

Tags: python3

```
testuser at ~]-pip3 install Request
Requirement already satisfied: Request in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: post in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Request) (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Request) (40.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: get in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Request) (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: query-string in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from get->Request) (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: public in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from query-string->get->Request) (2019.3.22)
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

testuser at ~]-pip install Request
Requirement already satisfied: Request in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: post in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Request) (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Request) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: get in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Request) (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: query-string in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from get->Request) (2019.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: public in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from query-string->get->Request) (2019.3.22)

testuser at ~]-which python
/anaconda3/bin/python

testuser at ~python3 -c "import Request" && echo $?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Request'

>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/testuser/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use `python` from non-standard location. 
Set `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables to let it know that:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/anaconda3/bin/python
export PYTHONHOME=/anaconda3/
```

Comment: Hi @rush, I have added the PYTHONPATH & PYTHONHOME in .bash_profile followed by sourcing it. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with setting up PATH, my sys.executable was pointing to "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin" and reset it to '/anaconda3/bin/python3'